WPF show validation errors under custom button
I am creating a WPF application with the MVVM pattern.
Validation errors are managed by using INotifyDataErrorInfo. The ViewModel implements INotifyDataErrorInfo.
For System.Windows.Controls controls it works great, but it doesn't work for custom controls.
In my application there is a custom button, like:
xaml:
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButtonWithValidation}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButtonWithValidation}">
        <Grid>
          <Button x:Name="PART_Button"
            Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

C#:
using System.Windows;

namespace MyApp.Controls;

public class MyButtonWithValidation: System.Windows.Controls.Button
{
  static MyButtonWithValidation()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButtonWithValidation), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyButtonWithValidation)));
  }
}

If I use this button, it is visible and it executes the command bound to it and even the validation is working as expected (in case of validation error, the button is disabled and the validation message is written below the button in red):
<local:MyButtonWithValidation
    Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
    Content="Search">
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock
                                Foreground="Red"
                                Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</local:MyButtonWithValidation>

Validation errors are managed by using INotifyDataErrorInfo. The ViewModel implements INotifyDataErrorInfo, like this:
private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> _errorsByPropertyName = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
public bool HasErrors => _errorsByPropertyName.Any();
public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs>? ErrorsChanged;

public IEnumerable GetErrors(string? propertyName)
{
    return propertyName is null || !_errorsByPropertyName.ContainsKey(propertyName)
         ? null
         : _errorsByPropertyName[propertyName];
}

In some cases I just apply a validation error, like:
AddError(nameof(SearchCommand), "Search validation error..."); // adds a new key-value pair ("SearchCommand", new List<string>() { "Search validation error..." }) to _errorsByPropertyName
As a result, there will be a validation error, and the error message is visible under the button.
Now, I want to move the Validation ErrorTemplate into MyButtonWithValidation:
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButtonWithValidation}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButtonWithValidation}">
        <Grid>
          <Button x:Name="PART_Button"
            Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
            <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
              <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                  <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox" />
                  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                          Foreground="Red"
                          Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" />
                      </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                  </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

In this case, if I use MyButtonWithValidation like this, it doesn't work as expected any more:
<local:MyButtonWithValidation
    Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
    Content="Search">
</local:MyButtonWithValidation>

In this case a red border is created around the button and the error message is not visible. It is like the validation error would be "handled" by WPF and not the validation error template.
Why is this and how could it be fixed?

The Validation.ErrorTemplate is not part of the Template but is a separate property, so you need a setter for it: <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">. See this answer for a working example: Validation.ErrorTemplate Style Issue

It looks promising, finnally it does what I want, thanks! There are still some minor issuses with my button, I will come back tomorrow with a more datailed answer.

Thank you @Oracle with your help I could make it work :)

Your whole template is problematic. Most of all, to template a Button you don't add another Button to the template. That's pointless and introduces a lot of other problems like focus issues as now 2 Buttons, the templated Button (MyButtonWithValidation) and the nested Button, both compete for device input and focus. For example, if both buttons execute their Click event, the Command is executed twice.

See Button ControlTemplate Example for an example template.

Next, the error template is not a member of the templated element. It's rendered on the adorner layer by the binding engine. The AdornedElementPlaceholder inside the template is the placeholder for the templated/adorned element - which in your case is the Button (and not a TextBox like your element name suggests). The placeholder is where your custom Button is embedded into the adorning layout you add to the error template.

Aren't you missing an additional setter when Validation.HasError is true? I'm using something similar to add easy validation errors to my inputs. For you it will be something like this I'd imagine:
<Button>
<Button.Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                <!-- your template -->
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Button.Style>

On another note, you might not need to TemplateBind the command. I believe WPF will overwrite the name of SaveCommand to Command, but I'm not 100% sure if that is the case.

Thank you @tovergieter. In the final solution the trigger was not necessary. Regarding the Command I hoped the same, I tried to omit the template binding of the command, but in that case the button click did not fire it.

@DánielErős ah okay, glad I could be of help :)

With the help of @Oracle and @tovergieter I could come up with this working solution:
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyErrorTemplate" TargetType="Control">
<StackPanel>
    <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="errorAdornerAnchor" />
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>

UPDATE Based on @BionicCode's suggestions
This was replaced
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButtonWithValidation}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButtonWithValidation}">
            <Button x:Name="PART_Button"
                Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"
                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MyErrorTemplate}" />

to this:
<Style x:Key="MyButtonWithValidation" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyApplicationButtonStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MyErrorTemplate}" />
</Style>

MyApplicationButtonStyle is another style in the application. This way I could get rid of the MyButtonWithValidation class and I can just use it like this:
<Button
    Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
    Content="Search"
    Style="{StaticResource MyButtonWithValidation}">


Your whole Button template is problematic. Most of all, to template a Button you don't add another Button to the template. That's pointless and introduces a lot of other problems like focus issues as now 2 Buttons, the templated Button (MyButtonWithValidation) and the nested Button, both compete for device input and focus. For example, if both buttons execute their Click event, the Command is executed twice.

See Button ControlTemplate Example for an example template.

In this context naming the content PART_Button doesn't make sense too. The extending MyButtonWithValidation control is already a Button. All it does with PART_Button it has to do it itself - in case you have any logic related to PART_Button. Right now, MyButtonWithValidation is wrapping another Button but is still accepting device input to act as a Button itself. Just remove the nested Button and add a ContentPresenter instead (see the provided link to the example template).

Thank you @BionicCode you are right and with your help I could finally find the right and much simpler solution to my original problem
